# Terminated due timeout

Tags: java

when i submit my code i get some successful test cases , but for some other test cases i get terminated due timeout , any help please ? i know it must be more optimized but i did my best to optimise and i still have the same problem , this is my code :

```
     public class Solution{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = scan.nextInt();//
    long tab[] = new long[T];

    String s;
    int n;
    int j=0;

    while(T-->0){
    s=scan.next();
    n=scan.nextInt();
    if(s.equals("add"))
    {
        tab[j]=n;
        j++;
    }
    if(s.equals("del"))
    {

        int i=0;
        boolean e=false;
        while(!e)
        {
            if(tab[i]==n)
            {
                e=true;
                tab[i]=-1;
            }
            else
            {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(s.equals("cnt"))
    {

        int count=0;
        int k=0;
            while(k<j)

        {
            if((tab[k]!=-1)&&(n&tab[k])==tab[k])
            {
                count++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        System.out.println(count);
    }}

}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us the code for a particular test that fails?

Comment: what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: when i submit my code i get "terminated due timeout" , i tried to optimise the most possible my code but i still geting the same problem , how can i fixe this ?

Comment: You shared your code, but not the test which is failing.  My guess would be that your class is failing to handle some inputs, and is left waiting for more input from `System.in`.  (For example, if the first integer misreported the number of arguments)  To be sure of this we'd need to see what the test is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of testcases are high then Scanner might be slower compared to BufferedReader. I use a custom class as Scanner might be helpful to you.

```
private static final class FastScanner {
    private final InputStream mIs;
    private final byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    private int curChar;
    private int numChars;

    public FastScanner() {
        this(System.in);
    }

    public FastScanner(final InputStream is) {
        this.mIs = is;
    }

    public int read() {
        if (this.numChars == -1) {
            throw new InputMismatchException();
        }
        if (this.curChar >= this.numChars) {
            this.curChar = 0;
            try {
                this.numChars = this.mIs.read(this.buf);
            } catch (final IOException e) {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            if (this.numChars <= 0) {
                return -1;
            }
        }
        return this.buf[this.curChar++];
    }

    public String nextLine() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        final StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (!isEndOfLine(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    public String nextString() {
        int c;
        while (isSpaceChar(c = read())) {
        }
        final StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    public long nextLong() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        long res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public int nextInt() {
        int c = read();
        while (isSpaceChar(c)) {
            c = read();
        }
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = read();
        }
        int res = 0;
        do {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9') {
                throw new InputMismatchException();
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = read();
        } while (!isSpaceChar(c));
        return res * sgn;
    }

    public int[] nextArray(final int n) {
        final int[] a = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = nextInt();
        }
        return a;
    }

    public long[] nextLongArray(final int n) {
        final long[] a = new long[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = nextLong();
        }
        return a;
    }

    public char[] nextCharArray(final int n) {
        final char[] buf = new char[n];
        int b, p = 0;
        while (isSpaceChar(b = read())) {
        }
        while (p < n && !isSpaceChar(b)) {
            buf[p++] = (char) b;
            b = read();
        }
        return n == p ? buf : Arrays.copyOf(buf, p);
    }

    public char[][] nextMatrix(final int n, final int m) {
        final char[][] map = new char[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            map[i] = nextCharArray(m);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public int[][] nextIntMatrix(final int n, final int m) {
        final int[][] map = new int[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            map[i] = nextArray(m);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public long[][] nextLongMatrix(final int n, final int m) {
        final long[][] map = new long[n][];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            map[i] = nextLongArray(m);
        }
        return map;
    }

    public boolean isSpaceChar(final int c) {
        return c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == '\t' || c == -1;
    }

    public boolean isEndOfLine(final int c) {
        return c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == -1;
    }
}
```